# How to access Apache environment variables in a Play Framework controller?

Tags: java, apache, playframework, playframework-2.0, shibboleth

I'm trying to integrate a Play Framework application with the Shibboleth authentication mechanism. I've been successful with this integration by using the "header injection" approach (in which Shibboleth injects Headers in the HTTP request with the necessary authentication data).

However, this is not advised as stated in the documentation where it is said "Use of this option should be avoided. Be sure to review the topic on spoof checking if you enable it".

With this in mind, I've decide to explore the other approach of using the Apache environment variables. However, I can't seem to find a way to access that information within a request instance (inside a controller).

If this were a traditional servlet, this would be done with:

```
HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("SOME_SHIBBOLETH_ATTRIBUTE");
```

How can one do the same in a controller with the Play Framework?

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Comment: You should first have a look at https://github.com/lightbend/config that is used for play config (and how it integrates env variables in config usable by the app)

Comment: Do you really need such tight/non-standard integration? Can it be something like pure https request from your play application to the shibboleth auth server (step 6 below)?:
1. User is trying to access resources in your play app (PA).
2. PA redirects the user to auth server (Shibboleth).
3. User uses login/password to authenticate on Shibboleth server.
4. Shibboleth sends unique token to user/browser and redirects the user back to your PA.
5. User/browser supplies auth token to PA.
6. PA sends token via secure connection (https) to shibboleth to validate it.